# How to properly use selectOneMenu onchange event when missing ajax support?

Tags: ajax, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I need help in this frequent problem in my project.

I want to refresh a list of values `list2` based on the currently selected value in another list `list1` using a method in my class bean, I want also to use Ajax instead of loading the entire page. The `rerender` property is not available in `selectOneMenu`.

I have tried:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="list1" value="#{bean.currentSelectedObject1}" onchange="submit()" 
        valueChangeListener="#{bean.methodAct}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listObjects1}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The menu that should be updated:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="list2" value="#{bean.currentSelectedObject2}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listObjects2}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I wonder if I can use some Richfaces tags to do this, or if there is another approach.

**UPDATE:**

The suggested solution gives me an error: `<a4j:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/a4j, but no tag was defined for name: ajax`
 
I can see `a4j:ajaxListener` with only `type` attribute   but no `a4j:ajax`, and also no `f:ajax` of any sort, I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016501/tag-library-supports-namespace-https-ajax4jsf-dev-java-net-ajax-but-no-tag-w), but I am using `JSF 2.2` not `JSF 2.0`.

Thank you

Comment: So, you're using the deprecated JSP view technology instead of its successor Facelets? That totally explains why the `<f:ajax>` didn't work for you. It's only available in Facelets, not in JSP. Abandon JSP and migrate to Facelets. Asking for workarounds is fruitless.

Comment: Many thanks @BalusC, by simply renaming the file to *.xhtml I was able to find `<f:ajax>`!.

Answer (score 1):

Following code refresh second list on change event in first list (select many list in example, but it is the same mechanism for select one list. Plus if there selected more than 1 item in first list, the second is empty):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.clients}" for="clientList" styleClass="boldlabel">
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </h:outputLabel>
    <h:selectManyListbox id="clientList"
        value="#{reportForm.selectedProviderIds}"
        label="#{msg.client}" size="8"
        style="min-width:120px;"
        valueChangeListener="#{reportForm.providerSelectionChanged}"
        immediate="true"
        required="true">
        <f:selectItems value="#{reportForm.providerList.list.list}"
            var="client"
            itemLabel="[#{client.providerCode}] #{client.name}"
            itemValue="#{client.providerId}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="retailerList, programList" />
    </h:selectManyListbox>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.retailers}"
        for="retailerList" styleClass="boldlabel" />
    <h:selectManyListbox id="retailerList"
        value="#{reportForm.selectedRetailerIds}"
        label="#{msg.retailer}" size="8"
        style="min-width:120px;"
        valueChangeListener="#{reportForm.retailerSelectionChanged}"
        immediate="true">
        <f:selectItems value="#{reportForm.retailers.list.list}"
            var="item"
            itemLabel="[#{item.retailerCode}] #{item.name}"
            itemValue="#{item.retailerId}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="programList" />
    </h:selectManyListbox>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And Java:

```
/**
 * Reaction on selection in client list box
 * @param event - Value change event with new value of selected clients
 */
public void providerSelectionChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    setSelectedProviderIds((Long[])event.getNewValue()); // sets new value(s) and clean related
    cleanClientRelatedComponents();
}

/**
 * Clean up source for client related UI components
 */
private void cleanClientRelatedComponents() {
    retailers = null; // needed for rebuild retailers
    setSelectedRetailerIds(null); // clean up retailer related source of data inside
}

/**
 * Sets selected retailer IDs and clean up source for related components
 * @param selectedRetailerIds the selectedRetailerIds to set
 */
public void setSelectedRetailerIds(Long[] selectedRetailerIds) {
    this.selectedRetailerIds = selectedRetailerIds;
    if (selectedRetailerIds != null && selectedRetailerIds.length == 1) {
        setSelectedRetailerId(selectedRetailerIds[0]);
    } else {
        setSelectedRetailerId(0); // rebuild list
    }
}
```